# Lambda NULL check in List foreach find method

Tags: c#, lambda

How can I check for NULL value in lambda expression having ForEach and Find methods.

For instance I've a below method which takes a comma separated list of values, iterate through them and for each value finds a SelectListItem which if found is marked as Selected. The issue comes when no matching item is found and it throws null reference exception.

```
private static void MarkListItemsSelected(string param, IList<SelectListItem> items)
{
    var filters = param.Split(';');
    filters.ToList()
     .ForEach(x => items.ToList()
                   .Find(y => y.Text.ToUpper().Equals(x.ToUpper()))
                   .Selected = true);
}
```

Comment: You don't need `ToList()`, it will split into an `Array`.

Comment: @Greg Arrays do not have a `ForEach` method.

Comment: @juharr They don't, but it is the equivalent of `foreach` so why create a `List` for `ForEach` when you could just do `foreach`.

Comment: items.ToList() is definitely unwarranted.

Comment: @Greg I totally agree and think `ForEach` is an abomination, but your comment sounded like they could just remove the `ToList`.

Comment: @Will that `ToList` is also there so they can use `Find` because `Find` is defined for `List<T>`, but not `IList<T>`.  But I don't think using `Find` is the best approach here.

Comment: @juharr Yeah but still.  The whole mess could be dropped to a single line using linq, anyhow.

Comment: @juharr Fair enough, I speak in an uncommon approach.

Comment: @Greg `ForEach` is defined in `List<T>.ForEach` so he does need the `ToList()`

Comment: Everyone that thinks `ForEach` is a good thing should read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Comment: @CoryCharlton `ForEach` is defined in a `List<T>` correct.  However, in what realm why would you purposefully split into an `Array` then force into a `List` for a `ForEach` when you could just as easy `foreach` on the `Array`.

Comment: @Greg I wouldn't. That said the OP did and asked a specific question regarding his implementation *shrug*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linq example:

```
private static void MarkListItemsSelected(string param, IList<SelectListItem> items)
{
    var filters = param.ToUpper().Split(';');

    items.ToList()
         .ForEach(x => { x.Selected = filters.Contains(x.Text.ToUpper());});
}
```

Traditional loops:

```
private static void MarkListItemsSelected(string param, IList<SelectListItem> items)
{
    var filters = param.ToUpper().Split(';');

    foreach( var x in items ) {
        x.Selected = filters.Contains(x.Text.ToUpper());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the `ToList()` and `Where` parts are flipped here. EDIT: That is, should be `items.Where(...).ToList().ForEach(...);`

Comment: Better yet, just use a `foreach` instead and there is no need for the `ToList`.

Comment: Ugh, side effects in Linq, please no.

Comment: I think the edited use of `.All` here is a step backward. Either use a `ToList().ForEach` or a `foreach` loop, but not `.All`; that would be abusing the _query_ nature of LINQ introducing side effects. Plus it's weird, rarely seen code. Plus it hinges on the fact that the property being changed (`.Selected`) happens to be a boolean.

Comment: Revised again. With regard to a foreach loop, I tend to prefer consistency, instead of mixing Linq and traditional loops.

Comment: @B2K `ForEach` absolutely is not Linq.  Linq is a set of extension methods on `IEnumerable<T>`.  `ForEach` is a method of `List<T>`.

Comment: One minor quibble with the latest edit (sorry!), the "traditional loops" version has slightly different behaviour in that the original code would not change the current value of the `SelectedListItem` if it didn't match the filter. That is, if it were `true` originally, and it didn't match, it stayed `true`. This new code would set it to `false`. (That said, this may actually be a _good_ thing for the OP, but I think it should be noted regardless.) EDIT: Actually, it's even worse: it could match an early filter, then be made `false` by a filter that doesn't match. I would consider it bugged.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I have modified both examples to match. My assumption, based upon the limited information provided is that param contains all of the selected elements. It is trivial to modify the examples if that is not the poster's intent.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a null check to lambda:

```
private static void MarkListItemsSelected(string param, IList<SelectListItem> items)
{
    var filters = param.Split(';');
    filters.ToList().ForEach(
        x =>
        {
            var found = items.ToList().Find(y => y.Text.ToUpper().Equals(x.ToUpper()));
            if (found != null)
                found.Selected = true;
        });
}
```

Comment: If you're going to have a multi-line lambda in a `ForEach` you might as well just use `foreach`.

Comment: @juharr I agree but was simply answering the question asked :)

Comment: IMHO there is nothing in that question that would required you to give an answer that uses `ForEach`

Comment: Actually the title says "foreach" not "ForEach".  So based on your logic we should only give `foreach` answers.